# How to add additional nodata value in GDAL?

Tags: gdal

I have a geotiff with a nodata value of -32768. How do I add 0 as additional nodata value in GDAL?

I am using the gdal.Translate to process my image.

```
from osgeo import gdal

src_ds = gdal.Open('example.tif')
options = gdal.TranslateOptions(
            format='COG', 
            creationOptions=['COMPRESS=LZW'], 
            noData=0)
ds = gdal.Translate(des_ds, src_ds, options=options)
```

When I added the `noData` argument in Translate Options, it replaces the former nodata value. What I want to achieve is to both have the -32768 and 0 as nodata values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. See the GDAL raster data model https://gdal.org/user/raster_data_model.html

> NODATA_VALUES: The value is a list of space separated pixel values
> matching the number of bands in the dataset that can be collectively
> used to identify pixels that are nodata in the dataset. With this
> style of nodata a pixel is considered nodata in all bands if and only
> if all bands match the corresponding value in the NODATA_VALUES tuple.

There can be only one nodata value per band. In addition, GeoTIFF format supports only one nodata value that affects all bands.

I suggest adding an alpha band. Update the values of the alpha band as you wish with a raster calculator.

Comment: Can I set the 0's to -32768? Like having a band math first?

Comment: Yes you can. For example with gdal_calc https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html. Unfortunately I do not feel comfortable with the Numpy syntax. Fortunately I have usually found usage examples from gis.stackexcange to copy and paste.  QGIS raster calculator is another option.